# Check if system is in Power saving mode

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-service

Is there a way i could know whether the system is in power saving mode when :

- user has enabled the power saver mode on manually
- the system goes into power saving mode when the battery is about to die?

I have noticed that the power saver mode kills my services, and my activity is dependent on the services.

Also my application uses `wake lock` permission.

Is there a way to know the mode is on/off so that I can reduce/limit the activities.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(power saving mode) is not an official AOSP feature and there are no ways to detect it with the official android SDK.

Comment: There must be some kind of flag or broadcast raised by the system.